# Loop over Laravel collection and store to key using Redis

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, redis

As a total amateur to redis I may be going about things in the total wrong way, one does suspect I am making things difficult for myself. That being said I am learning the basics and trying to achieve the result in how I thought would work.

I have a fair sized database in MySQL containing 40 million records.

As I don't know the full gist of Redis yet and the import methods and having the correct data structure I thought of a basic way:

Query MySQL using `laravel eloquent`, loop over the results and call `redis set` to store the values to the key.

Here's the thing, The database is OK postal codes and addresses, Each postal code contains many addresses.

Here's my code so far:

```
    $addresses = UkAddresses::where('postcode', 'N10AB')->get();
    $contCount = count($addresses);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $contCount; $x++) {
        $postcode = $addresses[$x]['postcode'];
        $redis = Redis::connection();
        $redis->set('postcodes.' . $postcode, json_encode(array(
                    'postcode' => $postcode,
                    'addresses' => array(
                        $addresses[$x]['address']
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        $response = $redis->get('postcodes.'.$postcode);
        $response = json_decode($response);
    }
```

Everything works fine apart from it only inserts a single address for that postcode, Here is a sample insert if i use `get postcode.N10AB`

```
{"postcode":"N10AB","addresses":["N10AB, Arena Enterprises UK Ltd, Flat 37, Selkirk House, Bemerton Estate, London "]}
```

My guess is there is something wrong with my loop when looping over the array that is returned from Laravel and that's the reason only 1 of the results is being passed to Redis?

Here is array returned from MySQL that I am trying to loop over and insert into Redis.

```
[0] 
postcode    "N10AB"
address "N1 0AB, Arena Enterprises UK Ltd, Flat 37, Selkirk House, Bemerton Estate, London "

[1]
postcode    "N10AB"
address "N1 0AB, Dumas Services, Flat 10, Selkirk House, Bemerton Estate, London "
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is the perfect and ideal solution however i have found a working solution below just in case anyone in the future has a similar situation as myself.

```
    $addresses = UkAddresses::where('postcode', 'N10AB')->get();
    $postcode = $addresses->first()->postcode;
    $items = array();
    foreach($addresses as $address){
        $items[] = $address['address'];
    }
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $redis->set('postcodes.' . $postcode, json_encode(array(
                'postcode' => $postcode,
                'addresses' => $items
            )
        )
    );
    $response = $redis->get('postcodes.' . $postcode);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    return response()->json($response);
```

Would be very interested to hear anyone else's view though as i'm sure there is a much easier and cleaner approach.

Comment: first of all, `first` may return null, you'll get trying to access postcode on null. as you're putting postcode as a variable then what is the point of extraction of postcode from the result set?